# cant configure usb wifi adapter on ubuntu 14.04 with kernel 4.2.0-42-generic

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, installation, adapter

I have been stuck with this issue now for couple of days.

I had seen many Q & A regarding same but I am confused and still not been able to make my usb wifi adapter working on ubuntu. (Same works with windows 7 partition )

I am able to make and make install the driver provided by manufactuter. even with modprobe I see my kernal module added. but output of lsmod shows that no process is using thins module.

Now issue is I am lost and cant head to any solution.

uname -a output:

4.2.0-42-generic #49~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 29 20:22:18 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

When I insert usb wifi adapter I get following in dmesg

rtusb init rt2870 --->
[ 1602.038165] usbcore: registered new interface driver rt2870
[ 1633.840109] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[ 1633.983746] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=7601
[ 1633.983754] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1633.983761] usb 2-1: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
[ 1633.983765] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: MediaTek
[ 1633.983769] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 1.0

Please guide

Comment: Try a newer version of Ubuntu -- 16.04 LTS is more likely to have support for newer hardware,

Comment: @DrMoishePippik thanks for advice but it is critical to ge this machine working with same Ubuntu version. Can you help?

Comment: Sorry, no; I've no experience with that hardware, but you might query the manufacturer.

Comment: Possibly answered [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/641724/how-to-install-rt2870-rt3070-wireless-driver).

Answer (score -1):

There's a ppa repo for this. 
I have tested it for RT2870 driver and it worked for me.
Plug your USB adapter in and run the following commands:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thopiekar/mt7601
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mt7601-sta-dkms
When the installation completes, click on the wi-fi network icon and you should see the USB adapter network interface
you can also install wicd for wired and wireless network management.